# How to check the accuracy of the results obtained from a Numerical simulation which used ODE solver solver_ivp in scipy?

Tags: scipy, numerical-methods, ode, solver

I have a question regarding the results we are obtaining from ODE solvers. I will try my best to briefly explain the question I have with me. For an example if we ran a simulation with ANSYS or may be any other FEA package, before we conclude our results there are many parameters to check the quality of the final results we obtained.

But in a numerical simulation, we are the one who gives relTol,absTol and other parameter values to improve the accuracy of the calculation to the solver. For an example if we select solve_ivp which is highly customisable solver available with SciPy.

Q1).How exactly make sure, the results of the solver is acceptable ?.

Q2). What are the ways we can check the quality of the final results we obtained?, before we make a conclusion based on the results obtained.

Q3) How further improve the accuracy of the by changing solver options?.

Highly appreciate if you can share your ideas with sample codings.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Q1 and Q2 are the same question. The reliability of the results will depend on the accuracy of the mathematical model wrt to the simulated phenomenon (f.i. assuming linearity when linearity is questionable) and the precision of the algorithm. You need to check if the method converges, and if it converges, must converge to a correct solution.

Ideally, you should compare your results to "ground truth" on typical problems. Ground truth can be obtained from a lab experiment, or by using an alternative method known to yield correct results. Without this, you will never be sure that your numerical method is valid, other than by an act of faith.

To understand the effect of the parameters and address Q3, you can solve the same problem with different parameter settings and observe their effect, one by one. After a while, you should get a better understanding on the convergence properties in relation to the parameter settings.